Why are whales’ click sequences called codas?
I read:

Variations in tempo, rhythm and length of the whales’ click sequences, called codas, weave a rich acoustic tapestry.

Why are whales’ click sequences called codas? It doesn't seem to be related to the musical meaning of coda.
I looked at a few dictionaries such as https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coda but I didn't see any explanation.

In phonology it refers to word-final sounds (analogous to musical codas that bring a passage to a close). Not sure how these sequences of whale sounds which are not closing sequences came to be called codas.

"Short series of 3 to 40 or more clicks are produced by sperm whales, Physeter catodon, in stereotyped repetitive sequences or codas." Sperm whale codas,
William A. Watkins; William E. Schevill
J. Acoust. Soc. Am. 62, 1485–1490 (1977)
https://doi.org/10.1121/1.381678

I don't think this is an ELL question.  From an ELL point of view "whale click sequences are called 'codas'"  That is all you really need to know. It's obviously highly technical (a term used specifically by Sperm whale researchers) and was probably just made up in the 1970s, perhaps based on "code"

@JamesK so are you going to vote to close all the etymology questions?

I think this has been discussed (search meta) etymology questions are at most borderline (the etymology of a word doesn't tell you what it means). So, yes, mostly. But they're very welcome over at ELU.

@JamesK got it, hopefully the policy will be clear one day

At least they didn't call them prepositions.
